# place icons on image and zoom

Tags: jquery, css, dictionary, zooming

I'm still a bit of a newby and have a huge problem. For a college project I am trying to create a map with icons on it. Basically, all of these are images - a map image and several icon images. I have placed the icons on the map with css. And now I am trying to createa zoom effect of the icons on mouseover. (The icons are hyperlinks, so clicks lead to a new page.)

Now I have two problems.

1. My CSS for placing the icons is all over the place. It works, but I have strange coordinates. (In an image that is 1000px x 600 px, some of the coordinates are 1000px from left, but the icon is in the middle of the page and things like that)
2. I have tried several jquery plugins, but whenever I attach them to an icon, either the icon vanishes (behind) the map or can be found somewhere completely else on the website. Or sometimes it just doesn't work at all. I have tried several different plugins...

Here are some snippets of the code I'm using.
for placing the icons:

```
    <div id="content">
    <div class="mapwrapper" align="center">
<img src="images/map.png" width="1010" height="620px" alt="Map of Dublin"/> 

<a href="bolands.php"><img class="icon" src="images/iconbolands.png" id="bolands" /></a>
<a href="cityhalldubcastle.php"><img class="icon" src="images/iconcityhall.png" id="cityhall" /></a>
<a href="fourcourts.php"><img class="icon" src="images/iconfourcourts.png" id="fourcourts" /></a>



</div> <!-- /mapwrapper-->
```

And the css:

```
#content {
padding-top:20px;
padding-bottom:50px;
    height:675px;
clear:both; 

 }


#mapwrapper {
position:relative; 
width: 1020px; 
height: 630px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;

 }


#content img {

position:relative;
z-index:0;

}
.icon {
position:absolute;
}

#bolands{
bottom:480px;
right:-700px;
z-index:10;
}

#cityhall {
bottom:435px;
right:90px;
z-index:15;
}
```

(etc)

Thanks for your help.

Kathi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you zoom in (assuming you mean enlarge) via CSS `:hover` pseudo-class and transitions?

See here (with other pics loaded in obviously): http://jsfiddle.net/TCDMn/

```
#content {
padding-top:20px;
padding-bottom:50px;
    height:675px;
clear:both; 

 }


#mapwrapper {
position:relative; 
width: 1020px; 
height: 630px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;

 }


#content img {


z-index:0;

}
.icon {
position:absolute;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    transition: all 2s;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s; /* Safari */
}
.icon:hover {
    height:75px;
    width:75px;
}
#bolands{
bottom:480px;
right:-700px;
z-index:10;
}

#cityhall {
bottom:435px;
right:90px;
z-index:15;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was so focussed on jquery and javascript, that I never even thought of a simple css :hover. Though my icons are now all over the place again. But that is fixable :-)

Comment: If this helped you, marking my answer as the resolution would help me back!